# Can I add a time interval to this animated easing css?

Tags: html, css, animation, easing

I have created an easing css but I will change it to "bottom up" direction. The problem is, I need to make it like moving twice and stop for a sec, then move again for twice and stop for a sec, and such repetition. I wanna add it on my website as the back to top button. Currently the button keeps moving. and as I said, I wanna make it move for twice, and stop for a sec and continue. Anyone knows?

Comment: use percent animation stop points instead of `from/to`; this way you can set a time for the whole animation and percentage the movements during the animation

Comment: `0%{ Code Goes Here }`

Comment: Thanks @HosseinMaktoobian that's helpful...

Comment: Thanks @George as well for updating and it's better...

Comment: Welcome @BenScmidth anytime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can comfortably play around with the [percentage setting](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp).

Simple example:

```
@keyframes mymove {
    0% {left: 0px;}
    20% {left: 20px;}
    40% {left: 0px;}
    60% {left: 20px;}
    100% {left: 20px;}
}
```

See this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wd1tt6fq/1/)